# Cursor.connection() returning columns but not rows

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django-project that needs to read data from a Postgres-DB and return the rows. I used a django.connections.cursor object to do so. When I execute the query, I get the columns or table-attributes back, but I dont get any of the rows back. I do know that the DB-table itself is populated with rows, so its not an empty db.

```
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        rv = cursor.execute("SELECT * from test_db_table")
        columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
        print "CURSOR IS : "
        print cursor
        print "Cursor descritpion : " + str(cursor.description)
        print "COLUMNS : "
        print columns
        print "ROW : 0"
        print cursor.fetchone()
        print "ALL ROWS : " 
        print cursor.fetchall()
        return [dict(zip(columns, row))
                for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(str(e))
        return []
```

Creating test database for alias 'default'...

CURSOR IS :

```
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f3b8a7e6050>
```

Cursor descritpion :

```
(Column(name='uuid', type_code=1043, display_size=None, internal_size=36, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='ossa_id', type_code=1043, display_size=None, internal_size=16, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='link', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='processed', type_code=16, display_size=None, internal_size=1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='name', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='description', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='affects', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='patches', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='references', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='notes', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='cve', type_code=25, display_size=None, internal_size=-1, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='notice_date', type_code=1082, display_size=None, internal_size=4, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='created', type_code=1184, display_size=None, internal_size=8, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None), 
Column(name='updated', type_code=1184, display_size=None, internal_size=8, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None))
```

COLUMNS :

```
['uuid', 'ossa_id', 'link', 'processed', 'name', 'description', 'affects',
 'patches', 'references', 'notes', 'cve', 'notice_date', 'created', 'updated']
```

ROW : 0

ALL ROWS : "

[]

```
=> select count(*) from test_db_table;
 count 
-------
   125
(1 row)
```

Can someone shed light on this ?

Comment: Why are you using raw quering? Much more better, faster and securer is to use the Django ORM.

Comment: In my case, the database and data is not local to the python app I'm running. It is owned by an outside submodule. Hence the cursor connection method.

Comment: for this case you have to set in the settings.py that you have the remote DB and you may also add a permission only for reading from the remote DB